# SharePoint Online CSOM/JSOM Get all root folders from Document Library and its all ItemChildCount (items including inside respective subfolders)

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom

We have document library having records more than 25000 items including many folders.
Using CSOM/JSOM need to get all root folders from Document Library (having more than 5000 items) and its all ItemChildCount (items including inside any subfolders) like below. I am able to get when items less than 5000. For more than 5000 I have tried using ListItemCollectionPosition, however the item count is not correct. I am expecting output like below (green box) item count. Appreciate your help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same question:

```
$Folders = Get-PnPListItem -List $Listname -PageSize 100 -Fields FileLeafRef  | Where { $_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder" }
```

when I have folder list over 5000 items I get:

> System.OutOfMemoryException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

get-pnplistitem, can it be set to not return folders recursively?  can you do a top to just pull in the first 100 items found?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/119859)